# Querying an array content in Cassandra using Stargate Document API

Tags: cassandra, stargate-oss

My document in Cassandra is

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "vowels": "aeu",
    "alpha":[
        "xyz",
        "efgh"
    ],
    "new": [
        {"name":"nam1"},
        {"name":"nam2"}
    ]
}
```

I am using Stargate Document API, query documents that has `alpha` value as `xyz`. I am trying to query using the where clause `where={"alpha.[*]":{"$eq":"xyz"}}`. This does not work and returns empty data. Is there a way to search using the Stargate Document API for arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the Stargate API.

I'm currently discussing it with the Stargate engineers and I will post an update once I have something more concrete. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** I've received feedback from the Stargate developers and logged issue [#1247](https://github.com/stargate/stargate/issues/1247) to address this problem. Thank you for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Noting here that this also reported in https://forum.k8ssandra.io/t/querying-an-array-using-stargate-document-api/318. Cheers!